# Inequality: $2\sqrt{xz}+2\sqrt{yz}+2\sqrt{xy}\geq 3x+3y+3z-3$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z$ be nonnegative real numbers satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.
Prove that:

$2\sqrt{xz}+2\sqrt{yz}+2\sqrt{xy}\geq 3x+3y+3z-3$

---

I have tried squaring both sides to get:

$8x\sqrt{yz}+8y\sqrt{xz}+8z\sqrt{xy}\geq14xy+14xz+14yz-18x-18y-18z+18$

(managed to use the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, but seems to get even more complicated)

---

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace the constant term $-3$ with $-3\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. This *homogenizes* the inequality, and from now on you can ignore the $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ normalization.
2. Consider substituting $a^2=x$, $b^2=y$, and $c^2=z$ so there aren't so many square roots to write out.
3. Eliminate the big nasty $\sqrt{a^4+b^4+c^4}$ by isolating it on one side and squaring, so that you end up with a 4th degree polynomial inequality. Do some simplifying. Use $\sum_{cyc}$ and $\sum_{sym}$ notation so it doesn't get too ugly.
4. I ended up with
   $$
   4abc(a+b+c) + 12\sum_{sym}a^3b \ge 22\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2.
   $$
   From here, AM-GM will suffice; the inequality is apparently not sharp, so some terms on the left-hand side are superfluous.

Comment: thanks! I followed through your instructive steps and it worked perfectly.